# Looking for cloud based ide/ides where i can setup apache-superset for developement

Tags: cloud9-ide, apache-superset, gitpod

I am looking to play with apache-superset on a cloud-based ide. I have it on my local. I tried unsuccessfully to set it up on gitpod. I wanted suggestions on where can I set it up, opensource preferably not necessarily. I believe cloud9 is 1 such place, but I am looking for other options before I settle. If you've ever set it up on any such platform, even if it is on gitpod and can help me, kindly do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Disclaimer: Gitpod staff]

You can indeed use Gitpod to work on apache-superset, and for that you'll just need a working configuration.

From what I can see in apache-superset's requirements, you'll need to get:

- PostgreSQL (e.g. by using Gitpod's official `gitpod/workspace-full-postgres` Docker base image)
- Redis (e.g. by installing it in a Dockerfile via `sudo apt-get install`)
- Various Python dependencies (e.g. by running `pip install .` after cloning)
- Various Node.js dependencies for the front-end (e.g. by running `npm install`)

Here is a basic configuration I wrote to achieve this:

https://github.com/jankeromnes/incubator-superset/commit/0d345a76ec8126fd1f8b9bc7b6ce4961bf3b593d

What it does is:

1. Create a Docker image with PostgreSQL and Redis
2. Once the repository is cloned, open 4 separate Terminals ("tasks"):

- Redis server
- Superset backend
- Superset worker
- Superset front-end

3. All dependencies will be installed automatically, and once the front-end is ready, it will automatically open in a web preview IDE side panel.

You can try it out by opening my personal fork of the apache-superset repository in Gitpod, e.g. by following this link:

https://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/jankeromnes/incubator-superset

Comment: thanks for your efforts @janx . The superset sets up a default id : pass that is (admin : admin) through which we can login if we didn't run the acc creation command. This does not work there. Also when I tried creating my own cred using the commands mentioned in there website i was able to login but the contents wouldn't load and it throws an error saying i do not have the necessary privileges. both of these things should not happen. Is there something that i've missed and should try?

Comment: Update : after trying few things the data is loading now.

Comment: Great that you got it working @Utkarsh Shrivastava! Could you please share if something in my solution needed to be adjusted, or what you tried that finally got it working?